# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{700} - 1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I was hoping someone could help me with this. I'm kinda stuck:

> Find the limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{700} - 1}{x-1}$$

I know the limit is 700, but I want to know why. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know a formula for $(x^n-1)/(x-1)$? If not, compute that fraction as a polynomial for $n=2$, $n=3$, etc., until you see a pattern; then prove the pattern.

Comment: You can use L'Hospital, like @ Claude Leibovici said, or do it in even more elemental way: $$ (x-1)\sum ^{699} _{k=0}x^k = x^{700} - 1$$
Then $$ lim_{n \rightarrow 1 } \frac{x^{700} - 1}{x-1} = lim_{n \rightarrow 1 } (1+x+x^2+...+x^{699}) = 1+1+...+1 \quad (700 \ times) = 700$$

Answer (score 4):

As Claude says in his comment de l'Hôpital is the simplest route. Another one is:

$$\frac{x^{700}-1}{x-1}=x^{699}+\cdots+x^{1}+1$$ Substituting $x=1$ on the right gives the outcome $700$.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$f(x)=x^n$$
then by the defintion of the derivative we have
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)=n$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^{700} -1}{x-1}= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{699} x^i$, therefore $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^{700} -1}{x-1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{699} x^i = 700$.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy if you are allowed to use L'Hopital:

the derivative of the numerator is $700x^{699}$. Taking $x\to 1$ you get the answer $700$.